# Open Neo4j graphs directly using Java code

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, graph-databases, graph-visualization

I have been trying to make a Maven-Web Application. I am calculating a few stuffs and then I need to display that in a graph which I am trying to display using Neo4j. The problem that I am facing right now is that I am able to connect my program to Neo4j but I am not able to directly open the browser which will display the graph.

My code is :

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException,     {
    File fileName=new File("C:/path/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb");
    GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory= new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb=dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(fileName);

    try(Transaction tx=graphDb.beginTx()){


      Node ANode=graphDb.createNode(NodeType.TSpot);
      ANode.setProperty("PId", "A");


      Node BNode=graphDb.createNode(NodeType.TSpot);
      BNode.setProperty("PId", "B");


      Relationship distance = ANode.createRelationshipTo(BNode,RelationType.Distance);
      distance.setProperty("distance", 40);


      tx.success();
      System.out.println("Success");

    }
    Config noSSL = Config.build()
            .withEncryptionLevel(Config.EncryptionLevel.NONE).toConfig();

    Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver( "bolt://localhost", AuthTokens.basic( "neo4j", "neo4j" ) , noSSL);
    Session session = driver.session();

    session.run( "MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n" );
    StatementResult result = session.run( "MATCH (n) RETURN n" );

    session.close();
    driver.close();
    graphDb.shutdown();
     }
```

The error that I am getting is this :

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.AuthenticationException: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketResponseHandler.handleFailureMessage(SocketResponseHandler.java:71)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.unpackFailureMessage(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:457)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.read(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:418)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.receiveOne(SocketClient.java:176)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.receiveAll(SocketClient.java:170)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.receiveAll(SocketConnection.java:200)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.sync(SocketConnection.java:155)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.init(SocketConnection.java:117)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.init(ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.java:53)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:58)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool$ConnectionSupplier.get(SocketConnectionPool.java:203)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool$ConnectionSupplier.get(SocketConnectionPool.java:185)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.BlockingPooledConnectionQueue.acquire(BlockingPooledConnectionQueue.java:92)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SocketConnectionPool.java:136)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool.acquire(SocketConnectionPool.java:75)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DirectDriver.newSessionWithMode(DirectDriver.java:50)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.BaseDriver.session(BaseDriver.java:64)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.BaseDriver.session(BaseDriver.java:57)
at final_project.App.main(App.java:87)
```

I think I need to reset the password for neo4j which is done the first time neo4j runs.

Comment: You state that you are able to connect your program to Neo4j, but your stack trace shows that you cannot. Can you clarify?

Comment: @cybersam I want that the graph automatically shown on the Neo4j browser without me opening the browser manually, resetting the password, typing cypher query and then receiving the graph. The program that I have written does not do that automatically, shows this error but when I manually open Neo4j , it shows the graph.